# Table <tr> appending again and again

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm creating `<tr>` dynamically and append this `tr` to `<tbody>` with jquery append method.

The `<table>` is created inside modal whenever I open modal without refreshing the page the same `<tr>` appending again and again to the old `<tr>`.

TABLE inside modal

```
<table class="table table-bordered tablesorter" id="work_aval">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="1" colspan="8" class="text-center"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="1" colspan="8" class="text-center">It is necessary to have some element of weekend availability. If you tick the weekends this could be applied as alternate as well
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
      <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

AJAX call for `<tr>` append

```
$("#work_aval tbody").append(response.availability);
```

[image: My desired output]

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: i think you need to clear the inner html first and then append.

Comment: So... don't append it again?  What's the issue?   It's your code that's appending the row.  Did you meant to *replace* the row?  Overwrite it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('#work_aval tbody').empty();
This line works for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try html() instead of append() method?

Ex:

```
$("#work_aval tbody").html(response.availability);
```

Comment: Is this a comment? Request?  Or is it meant as an answer?